# Stack associated to Lie group and manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, stacks

Given a Lie group $G$, we have a Lie groupoid $(G\rightrightarrows *)$  and stack $BG=B\mathcal{G}$  of principal $G$ bundles.

Given a smooth manifold $M$, we have Lie groupoid $(M\rightrightarrows M)$  and stack $\underline{M}$ whose objects are smooth  maps to $M$.

Given Lie group $G$, we have two Lie groupoids associated to it :

- $(G\rightrightarrows *)$ if we consider Lie group structure.
- $(G\rightrightarrows G)$ if we ignore group structure and treat it as a manifold.

We have corresponding stacks associated :

- $(G\rightrightarrows *)$ gives stack $B(G\rightrightarrows *)$, usually denoted by $BG$.
- $(G\rightrightarrows G)$ gives stack $B(G\rightrightarrows G)$, usually denoted by $\underline{G}$.

As any Lie group is a manifold, shouldn't there be some relation with notions $BG$ and $\underline{G}$? I see they are not same. 
How are they related?

It is not even the case that the Lie groupoid $(G\rightrightarrows *)$ is pull back of $(G\rightrightarrows G)$ or the otherway around.

---

I do not know counter part in Algebraic geometry.

Feel free  to (I request you to) relate  this to algebraic geometry version of stacks.

Comment: Can some one up voting the question leave a message :P  :D

Comment: I don't understand what is the utility of "Are they same?  I see they are not same."

Comment: @LSpice I have edited it. :) Bad English skills :)

Comment: It's nothing to do with algebraic geometry, just pure stack theory.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I though similar question can be asked from algebraic geometry perspective so that it will be convenient for them to think..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\underline{G}$ is the homotopy loop space of $BG$.

More precisely, the two terminal maps $G\rightarrow pt$ and $G\rightarrow pt$
yield a weak equivalence $\underline{G} \rightarrow  pt\times_{BG} pt$,
where the right side denotes the homotopy pullback of the diagram $pt\rightarrow BG\leftarrow pt$
and $pt$ denotes the representable stack of a smooth manifold given by a single point.

Comment: I will say what I understand.. For Lie group $G$, we have obvious map of stacks $\underline{*}\rightarrow BG$ (which is actually an atlas for $BG$). Consider the $2$-fibre product $\underline{*}\times_{BG}\underline{*}$. Here, $*$ denote singleton space and $\underline{*}$ denote the stack associated to singleton manfold. What does it mean to say a weak equivalence $G\rightarrow \underline{*}\times_{BG}\underline{*}$.. I only know weak (Morita ??) equivalence in case of Lie groupoids.. Does it  mean weak equivalence as in page 9 of http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~noohi/papers/quick.pdf?

Comment: searching in google said that, "loop space" of space $BG$ is a space that is homotopy equivalent to $G$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442805/the-loop-space-of-the-classifying-space-is-the-group-omegabg-simeq-g) Can you please tell me How should I relate with my question?

Comment: Where by "homotopy pullback" Dmitri means the pullback of stacks in the appropriate 2-categorical way (or, if you like, the comma object). The loop space here is **not** the same as the topological loop space (though there is a relation there too), but a higher-categorical analogue (cf https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/loop+space+object). "Weak equivalence" means Morita equivalence of the corresponding Lie groupoids, but as I've said elsewhere, I don't think "Morita equivalence" is the best phrase to use.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik:  What David Roberts said.  In addition, be aware that BG in the hyperlinked question is _not_ BG in your question: the former BG is a space (alias ∞-groupoid), whereas your BG is a Lie groupoid, or, alternatively, a stack of ∞-groupoids on the site of smooth manifolds.  The former BG is the shape of the latter, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+modality.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I saw nlab page... It says, loop space object of $BG$ is the stack $\underline{*}\times_{BG}\underline{*}$...

Comment: @DmitriPavlov So, you are saying there is a weak equivalence of Lie groupoids $(G\rightrightarrows G)$ and the Lie groupoid representing the stack $\underline{*}\times_{BG}\underline{*}$... Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, that's what his answer says.

Comment: Can you give  a reference or you think it is straight forward. I did not yet try to prove... @DmitriPavlov

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The loop-deloop adjunction is discussed in Goerss and Jardine, “Simplicial Homotopy Theory”, V.3, V.4, and V.5.